# Two-way databinding screen orentation change changes value

Tags: android, android-room, android-databinding, android-livedata

I'm using two-way databinding.
I have some data inside my Room databse and depending on what user writes in edittext showing that value in textview.

When I rotate screen, value gets updated. At fist its empty string then back to how it was. I know this is normal behavior of activity lifecycle.

So I would like to know the best way to get rid of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

EditText:

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/edtOddelek"
            android:text="@={viewModel.loginOddelek}"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtGeslo" style="@style/adoEditTextStyle"/>
```

TextView:

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtOddelek"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.oddelek}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/orangeDark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtOddelek"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
val loginOddelek = NonNullMutableLiveData<String>("")

val oddelek:LiveData<String> = Transformations.switchMap(loginOddelek){
    settingsModel.getSifrPr(it)
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want to get rid of? `loginOddelek` noramlly should not be affected by screen rotation, so `getSifrPr` also will not get called.

Comment: When screen rotation occur value of edittext goes to "" (empty string). Then value goes back to how it was. This happens due to lifecycle. If there is longer running task that is problem. Could be using onTextChanged but I really want all code to  be as clean as prossible.